# real time validation of username using javascript and ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I've written a script for my registration form that if there's a keyup event on the username input field, then javascript checks if the username entered is valid and if it's then an ajax function is called to check its availability.

It's working fine. But username can be entered without doing a key up, what to do for those cases? E.g. **username can be entered by clicking the input field and selecting a name suggested by the browser, Or by using an auto-form filler. There's no "keyup" in these cases, so what to do for these cases?**

And if I am missing some case then pls tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**setInterval is the only way.**

Sources:

[I want to trigger an event every single time data changes in an HTML text input field regardless of focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835337/i-want-to-trigger-an-event-every-single-time-data-changes-in-an-html-text-input?rq=1)

[jQuery: What listener do I use to check for browser auto filling the password input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066406/jquery-what-listener-do-i-use-to-check-for-browser-auto-filling-the-password-in)

Answer (score 4):

Bind the callback to the `change` event too.

Instead of `$('username_input').keyup` or `$('username_input').bind('keyup', callback)` use

```
$('username_input').bind('keyup change blur', function () {
    //
})
```

**[UPDATE]**

If you are not using jQuery try

```
function checkUserName() {
   // Ajax validation code
}
userinput = document.getElementById('yourusernameinputid');
userinput.onclick = userinput.onchange = userinput.onblur = checkUserName;
```

on a side note, you should try learning jQuery. It could save you a lot of time, and help you make better sites in less time.

**[UPDATE 2]**

It looks like there is no way to detect change via autofill using events. You need to set a timer to automatically check your input at fixed interval and check with you last value.

```
(function() {
   // It is always better to use a closure to prevent the value from 
   // getting overwritten by another piece of code
   var value = '';
   setInterval(2000, function() {
      if (userinput.value != value) {
           checkUserName();
           value = userinput.value;
      }
   });
})();
```

Comment: I don't know jquery. The onchange attribute is working but only when the input field is deselected. I want that as some value goes inside the field, the function should be called.

Comment: After you set the value, trigger the event manually, like: $( "#yourField" ).change(). And the handler will execute.

Comment: As Joyce said, I would recommend you to learn jQuery. It's a very powerfull library and easy to learn.

Answer (score 0):

- Test the username when:

  - The blur event occurs (when the text field loses its focus), and
  - Before the user sumits the form, or
  - The change event occurs (I think this is the best).

Comment: change is triggered only when the field is deselected.